# Convert date and time string into datetime

Tags: powershell

I've got a variable of type string which looks something like this
$string = "07/07/2019 18:00". I want to convert this variable into an variable of type datetime. The format should be MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM

```
$date = '07/07/2019'
$time = '18:00'
$datetime = $date + ' ' + $time
$datetime = [datetime]::ParseExact('$datetime', 'MM/DD/YYYY_HH:MM', $null)
```

Using the code above, I get an error message telling me:

Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Is there another way to go?

Answer (score 3):

Your format string used wrong specifiers, namely `DD` and `YYYY`; see [custom date and time formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Change your code to

```
 $date = '07/07/2019'
 $time = '18:00'
 $datetime = $date + ' ' + $time
 $datetime = [datetime]::ParseExact($datetime, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm', $null)

 $datetime
```

Also be aware to pass `$datetime` as reference and not as single quoted string.

You find above code under this [link](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/n0slJbEkVcFWQd3AXB@IjAwMLdW5VEoyc8GChhZWBgbqEEVQMYgGbQV1INRWAKtEkY@GsWOtrAISi4pTXSsSk0s04Ep0FNR9ffVTUvQrgUDBw8MqN1ddR0ElrzQnR5MLyaT//wE).

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 2):

```
[datetime]'07/07/2019 18:00'


Sunday, July 7, 2019 6:00:00 PM
```

Or

```
[datetime]'7/7'
[datetime]'18:00'
[datetime]'6pm'
```

Then you can add or subtract them, but then the answer is a [timespan].